# Horizontal tab bar responsive bootstrap / blazor

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm creating a tab control in blazor and I want my horizontal tab bar to be responsive when there will be a lot of tabs. 
I tried to handle it with my `tc-tabs` but the scrollbar is not displayed and it display the display others tab on a new line.

[image]

I'm looking for 2 different solution:
  -One where the overflow is handled with a scrollbar
  -An other one where the overflow is handled with 2 arrows at each side of the tab bar (that I can try to manage using razor fonctionalities)

And also, i'm trying to fix the close button on the top right corner of each tab, especially when the tab name is too long.

**Edit (Fixed the close button on right + text overflow inside the tab):**

Still having trouble with the scrollbar solution based on this post: [Bootstrap horizontal scrollable tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582520/bootstrap-horizontal-scrollable-tab-bar)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tc-tabs">
    @foreach (Tab tabItem in ItemsSource) {
        <li class="tc-tab @(SelectedItem == tabItem ? "tc-tab-active" : string.Empty)">
            <div @onclick="@(() => ActivatePage(tabItem))">
                <span class="tc-tab-title @(SelectedItem == tabItem ? "active" : string.Empty)">
                    @tabItem.Title
                </span>
            </div>
            <button class="close tc-tab-close" type="button" aria-label="Close" @onclick="@(() => DeletePage(tabItem))">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

css:

```
tc-tabs {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
}

.tc-tab {
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    float: none;
}

.tc-tab-active {
    background-color: darkgray;
    color: white;
}

.tc-tab-title {
    width: 85%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

.tc-tab-close {
    width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble with the scrollbar, i'm trying to do the same as this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582520/bootstrap-horizontal-scrollable-tab-bar but still the same problem. I don't understand why it doesn't have the same behavior.

Comment: Found the problem, came from the property of `nav` -> `flex-wrap: wrap` that need to be remove in order to handle the overflow with the scrollbar

Answer (score 2):

The following, though not a complete solution, is working. I actually did it to suggest a path you should follow in order to create the Horizontal Tab Bar. 
* Create a Tab Component to represent a single tab
* Create a TabBar component that can contain multiple tab objects, and manipulate them as necessary.

Note that each tab contains a closing button that 'close' the tab when clicked.

### Tab.razor

```
  <li style="height:auto; width:inherit; padding:5px; border: 1px solid blue; text-align:right;">
        <span style="float: left">@Title</span>
        <a href="#" @onclick="@(() => Close.InvokeAsync(ID))" role="button">X</a>

    </li>
     <div style="padding:0px; ">@ChildContent</div> 


 @code {
      [Parameter]
      public int ID { get; set; }
      [Parameter]
       public string Title { get; set; }

      [Parameter]
      public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

      [Parameter]
      public EventCallback <int> Close {get; set;}
 }
```

### TabBar.razor

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tb-tabs">
<li><a href="#" @onclick="@GoForward" role="button">--></a></li>
@foreach (var tab in tabs)
{
    <Tab ID="@tab.ID" Title="@tab.Title" Close="@Close"></Tab>

}

<li><a href="#" @onclick="@GoBackward" role="button">&lt;--</a></li>
</ul>



@code {

    // TODO: Add code to go forward
    private void GoForward()
    {

    }

    // TODO: Add code to go backward
    private void GoBackward()
    {

    }

    List<NavTab> tabs = new List<NavTab>
        {
            new NavTab{ ID = 1, Title = "Long Name Example 1"},
            new NavTab{ ID = 2, Title = "Small" },
            new NavTab{ ID = 3, Title = "Long Name Example 2" }
       };


    private void Close(int ID)
    {
        RemoveNavTab(ID);

    }

    // You can also create a similar method to add tabs dynamically
    public void RemoveNavTab(int ID)
    {

        tabs.Remove(tabs.Where(alert => alert.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault());
        StateHasChanged();
    }


    public class NavTab
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }


    }

 }
```

Place the following in the MainLayout above the anchor element "About"

```
<div>
   <TabBar />
</div>
```

Run your app and test the code...

Note: I've create the outline, and all you've got to do is add necessary functionalities on top of it. Use FlexBox to manage the tabs in css. Add code to determine the size of the text to display, etc.